# dataset validation policy minimumSizeMB for Azure Blob

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

If I set minimumSizeMB policy for an external dataset of type AzureBlob, does it mean that ADF is going to check total file size in FolderPath (I could have hundreds of files in a given FolderPath with varying size) or it is going to consider only those files in the FolderPath as input which qualify minimumSizeMB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed through an experiment that it's the total size of all the files